# How to not show profile picture of users in list view?

Tags: list-view, thumbnail

We have users associated to list items.

The way Sharepoint 2013 displays these names in list views is WITH thumbnail of their profile picture.

Is there any way to turn off this feature and show a list of the names instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it just a 'person or group' column that's set to show the profile picture. If so you can go to list setting, modify the column and change the 'Show Field' option so that the users picture isn't included.

Comment: Counter-intuitive in my eyes. Ideally the VIEW should be able to determine how things are displayed, not? (speaking from MVC training)